# Excel - finding values that "look like"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook with a ton of sheets. In the first sheet "users" i have userdata, firstname, lastname, email, etc. all neatly split from a CSV file.
In the other sheets, i have some of the names and need the emails from the "users" sheet.

The problem is, that the names on all the other sheets are all in one cell with both first- and lastname like, and in the users-sheet it's split. Also, in the other sheets it might be written as "Mike Anderson", "Mike, Anderson" or even "Anderson, Mike".

Does anyone have an idea to a macro / VBA script / formular, that would help me find and copy the corresponding emails?

Comment: Are there no other columns that may provide unique matches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check for `Mike Anderson`, `Mike, Anderson` or even `Anderson, Mike`, you can use `.Find` and `.FindNext` .

See this example

**Logic**: Use the Excel's inbuilt `.Find` method to find `Mike` and once that is found, simply check if the cell also has `Anderson`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String

    On Error GoTo Err

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oRange = ws.Columns(1)

    SearchString = "Mike"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, "Anderson", vbTextCompare) Then _
        FoundAt = aCell.Address

        Do
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                If InStr(1, aCell.Value, "Anderson", vbTextCompare) Then _
                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

More on `.Find` and `.Findnext` [here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/).

Comment: +1 for creative solution! (Also, I'm saving this one for future use)

Comment: I like it. Still, I am surprised that you are using  `Else ExitLoop = True` instead of `Else Exit Do`. Is there a reason to prefer one over the other? Also - would you want to check the names are next to each other? You don't want to find "Mike decided to install Anderson windows".

Comment: @Floris: Yes you can use `Exit Do` as well. Regarding your 2nd point, it is a valid point. In case the user has data like `Mike decided to install Anderson windows` then yes, the user has to incorporate that in the code as well. I have not covered each and every scenario. I m sure OP can modify the code to suit his/her needs :)

Comment: @Floris: Suggestion incorporated.

Comment: Great answer! But i already have names like "Anderson, Mike" in one cell, and need to find the email in another sheet where it's "Anderson" in one cell and "Mike" in another - does that make sense?

Comment: @user2266485: Yes it does. You can use `.Offset` If you can show us a sample data then maybe I can elaborate

Comment: I can give you an example of the data, can I email it to you? There are a lot of emails and stuff that I can't post in public.

Comment: You can replace those emails with fictitious emails and then upload the data?

Comment: Right :) [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1107227/dataset.xls)

If you look at the sheet "NS Area" - i need the emails from the "users"-sheet :)

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Now since the data is inconsistent(some have "," and some don't) so you will have to loop through those cell and then split on comma/space so that you get the firstname and lastname and then use that to search the user's sheet and if a match is found, you will use the offset to check if the other name also matches :) Give it a try and if you get stuck post the code that you tried and we will take it from there?

Comment: Ok thanks, going to try it out! I'm not really used to working with VBA, and I'm on a borrowed Mac right now (usually PC user), so I just have to figure everything out ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the VBA **LIKE** operator with wildcards perhaps?

```
If activecell.text LIKE "*Paul*" then ...
```

and also, as **Floris** has pointed out, you would need `Option Compare Text` set at the top of the module to ensure your test isn't *case-sensitive*

Comment: Why the three asterisks? Isn't a single `*` before and after enough? Also - you will want to have `Option Compare Text` set so you are not case sensitive ... unless you want to be.

Comment: This is a great solution for the LIKE

Answer (score 0):

The searched value can be easily found in all the workbook with the textbox and option buttons that they are added to the workbook's first sheet .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ3tG.jpg)

Through option buttons,value in textbox  can be searched as two types , whole or part :

```
If Sheets(1).OptionButton1 = True Then
Set Firstcell = Cells.Find(What:=Sheets(1).TxtSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
Else
Set Firstcell = Cells.Find(What:=Sheets(1).TxtSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
End If
```

I too have used **Find & FindNext Method** in template coding :

```
If Not Firstcell Is Nothing Then
Firstcell.Activate
Firstcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 19

With Sheets("New_Report").Range("A1")
.Value = "Addresses Of The Found Results"
.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End With
Sheets("New_Report").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("New_Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = oSheet.Name & "!" & Firstcell.Address(False, False)

Call Create_Hyperlinks  'Hyperlinks are generated in New Report Sheet

If MsgBox("Found " & Chr(34) & Sheets(1).TxtSearch & Chr(34) & " in " & oSheet.Name & "!" & Firstcell.Address & vbLf & "Do You Want To Continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
Exit Sub: End If

While (Not NextCell Is Nothing) And (Not NextCell.Address = Firstcell.Address)
                    counter = counter + 1
Firstcell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Set NextCell = Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell)

If NextCell.Row = 2 Then
Set NextCell = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, LastColumn)).FindNext(After:=ActiveCell)
End If

If Not NextCell.Address = Firstcell.Address Then
NextCell.Activate
NextCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
Sheets("New_Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = oSheet.Name & "!" & NextCell.Address(False, False)

Call Create_Hyperlinks

If MsgBox("Found " & Chr(34) & Sheets(1).TxtSearch & Chr(34) & " in " & oSheet.Name & "!" & NextCell.Address & vbLf & "Do You Want To Continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
Exit Sub: End If

End If 'If Not NextCell.Address = Firstcell.Address Then
NextCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

Wend
End If
Next oSheet
End If
```

All results are listed as hyperlinks in the generated report sheet with different a function.