# Multiple Substitute from a list using wildcard characters Excel

Tags: excel, substitution, vba

I'm trying to remove and replace in a long column of string variables (>14,000) specific misspellings or redundancies from a list that I have made in another column.

So far I am able to replace specifically from the list using the following code:

```
Function WordsOut(WordList As Range, TargetString As String) As String
Dim rng As Range, str As String

str = TargetString
For Each rng In WordList
    If InStr(1, str, rng.Value) <> 0 Then
        str = Trim(Replace(str, rng.Value, ""))
    End If
Next
WordsOut = str
End Function
```

But, what I can't do is use wildcard characters as input. I want some of the values in my WordList to be Age** for example, and have my function remove all examples of that. I know I need to use Find somehow, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Please help! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - finding values that "look like"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928469/excel-finding-values-that-look-like) OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087446/excel-vba-wildcard-search OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538493/vba-excel-find-string-wildcard

Comment: It is not a duplicate of any of those. I need to cross check to a list- thats what makes it different. I need to cycle through the values, including wildcards.

Comment: In my opinion that doesn't make your problem any different but merely makes your question an "extension" to any of the referenced solutions. So, you'll have to wrap the referenced solutions into a loop to cycle your list. Did I get this right? If so, that makes your question a compounded question asking (1) how to make a wildcard search and then (2) asking how to cycle a list with a loop. For both type of questions there are ample solutions on this site. If you are struggling to put the two together then *please give it a try* and (if you fail) post your attempt here.